# looping foreach and set to paragraph

Tags: php, arrays

I have have this array:

```
    $array = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                  Price => 1.25,
                  Number => 15 
                ),
           array( Title => "daisy", 
                  Price => 0.75,
                  Number => 25,
                ),
           array( Title => "orchid", 
                  Price => 1.15,
                  Number => 7 
                )
         );
```

And I used foreach to disect each data from the array,
        $header = "I want this format to my email:";

```
    $closing = "Thank you.";
    foreach($array as $row){
    $title = row['Title'];
    $price = row['Price'];
    $number = row['Number'];


    $details ="
    Title: $title
    Price: $price 
    Number: $number
    ";
    $message ="
    $headers

    $details

    $closing
    ";
    }

    mail($email, $data, $detail);

    //And I want to mail the result with a format same as below,
```

I want this format to my email:

This is the 1st record:

Title: data

Price: data

Number: data
,

Title: data

Price: data

Number: data
,

Title: data

Price: data

Number: data

Thank you.

but it only shows 1 data from my array,

how can I show all data from my array with this kind of format? Need help ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the message assignment outside the loop and build the details value in the loop

```
$closing = "Thank you.";
$details = '';
foreach($array as $row){
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $price = $row['Price'];
    $number = $row['Number'];


    $details .= "
Title: $title
Price: $price 
Number: $number
";
}
$message ="
$headers

$details

$closing
";

mail($email, 'subject', $message);
```

http://codepad.org/Qi9RZs2Y

Comment: I tried this one, but it stills return 1 set of data from my array

Answer (score 0):

you need to `append` the next comming values like

```
// loop {
 $details .="
Title: $title
Price: $price 
Number: $number
";

// }
$message ="
$headers

$details

$closing
";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$details= "";
foreach($array as $row){
    $details.= "Title: {$row['Title']}
    Price: {$row['Price']} 
    Number: {$row['Number']}";
}
```

Your foreach is not correct try this code instead